# import excel to mysql to treeview in php

Tags: php, mysql, excel, import

I want to import data from excel file which is in parent child relationship to mysql database and display it as a tree view using mysql database data,

Any help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Export the file as CSV, use [mysqlimport](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlimport.html) to import said CSV into the database. If you need further assistance, leave a comment here and we'll see.

Comment: thanks for the reply,the file contains 1 parent and 3 child , how can i store it in mysql without loosing database space, and how can i make relationship between parent and child ids

Comment: export the file as CSV, post a snippet on pastie.org and I'll be happy to have a look

Comment: thanks, and i have exported that file in csv and then  i have used http://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/ that helps me to solve my issue